# How to align different elements horizontally in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootply demo => http://www.bootply.com/hnqGW3IG8S

As can be seen, the "Page 1 of 206" `<div>` is a little higher than `Prev` and `Next`.. I tried `line-height` and `margin-top` to adjust the position but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you need like this?? http://www.bootply.com/2da6YFqfLe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if [this](http://www.bootply.com/rEgwmQyHpx) helps you.

CSS

```
    .page-number {
        display: inline;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

Comment: I tried to modify the `margin-bottom` of `button`, but this solution looks better.